# Why does my menu bar resort to :hover behavior onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have I'm using the dsmoothmenu jquery plugin to generate a toolbar on the top of my page -- About a month ago, the page started loading (most of the time) with the first item of the menu bar exposed -- as if the user were hovering over the item.  I've spent hours trying to figure out what's causing this and haven't made any progress.

I have another page which uses the same exact markup for the menu, and the same dsmoothmenu js/css, but which doesn't exhibit the aforementioned behavior.  So I figure it's got somehting to do with perhaps a meta tag, or a style that's being overwritten.  By investigating with the inspector, it seems as though the `ul#other_cities` element is being given `display:block` by something, which is overriding the default style of `display:none`, which should be active until the user hovers over the element.

Here's an an example of the problem:  http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/la/

And a working example:  http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/iphone.html

**EDIT:**  So I've found that the problem will only manifest itself if the mouse is OUTSIDE of the window when the page finishes loaded.  If you keep the mouse hovering over the page, the menu bar will not slide down.  This along with the fact that it only seems to happen in chrome, leaves me really confused.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem in Safari (Webkit)

Comment: hmmm, you're right, it doesnt seem to be happening in safari anymore.  It is still happening in chrome.

Comment: nice:  Chrome & Safari are both Webkit browsers so that's odd.

Comment: @Sparky672, you're telling me!  I've tried tons of methods and haven't been able to learn anything about why this is happening.

Comment: Have you [validated](http://validator.w3.org) your code yet? I'm seeing a bunch of errors.

Comment: There are some errors, but i dont think they're related.

Comment: seems to be a Chrome specific error; works in Firefox/Linux (but not Chrome). Very odd indeed.

Comment: try adding it as an inline style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see your problem in Chrome when I right-click the link and then "Open link in new tab" or " ... new window" which opens the window in the background. This leaves me with this conclusion.

Google's Chrome, for some weird reason, positions a "virtual" pointer at position top:1, left:1 which triggers the script. As soon as we bring in the actual "physical" pointer this position takes over and the problem is gone.

As this seems to be a problem with Chrome we can prevent this only with a little trick. I'd say we give the main div#wrapper some breathing room to the left with a margin? Or maybe something to the top like the second example which works!!!

Comment: Wow, nice observation!  I had all but given up on this problem, but margin-left:1px on the first li seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

So far I've been able to find out that the onMouseOver event actually fires when the page is loaded.

Since I don't have direct access to the JS files search for the word 'trigger' in all the file (not the jquery ones) and try to find out if it might be calling that at any point.

I will do more research when I have time.

Comment: If you search the DOM inspector for 'trigger', it looks like it appears twice in main.js, which is the google maps js file.  i dont think either appearance is related.  How were you able to discover that the onMouseOver event is fired on page load, thats quite an interesting clue!  I appreciate any and all help you can offer.

Comment: Before the page had fully loaded I bound my own hover function which displayed an alert and it's triggered as soon as the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Cool, ill continue trying to figure out what my be causing it.  ive updated the OP with some more background info.

Answer (score 0):

If Nicklas is correct and hover is for some reason firing onload, try wrapping the js of the hover function in your menu javascript with the following conditional:

```
if(event.target == this) { //Check if the hover event actually targets the object.

//Hover Code//

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That didn't do it.  I'm console logging the event here, if you want to see:  http://7.latest.foodtrucksmap.appspot.com/la/   For some reason, the browser is absolutely convinced that a mouseenter has occurred over the first list element.